# Error: Cannot find module 'code-point-at' while writing any npm commands

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, module, point

#### Configurations:

**System : Ubuntu v21.10**

**node : v16.14.0**

**npm : v6.13.7**

#### Problem :

It was working well until last ubuntu software update,Now its throwing "**Error: Cannot find module 'code-point-at**' while writing any npm commands" because of **code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'**
I have attached terminal Screenshot,please help me solve this issue.

#### Terminal:

[Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud4OR.png)

```
ssns@nits-hp-15-notebook-pc:~$ npm --version
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module 'code-point-at'
Require stack:
- /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/wide-align/node_modules/string-width/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/wide-align/align.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/gauge/lib/render-template.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/gauge/lib/plumbing.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/gauge/lib/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/lib/log.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/log-shim.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exit-handler.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/wide-align/node_modules/string-width/index.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/wide-align/node_modules/string-width/index.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/wide-align/align.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/gauge/lib/render-template.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/gauge/lib/plumbing.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/gauge/lib/index.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/lib/log.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/log-shim.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exit-handler.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
  ]
}
ssns@nits-hp-15-notebook-pc:~$
```

*Thanks in Advance.. :)*

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on Windows - even `npm -v` would throw the same error. I'm unable to find the root cause of the issue, but found the following workaround.

I found out that the folder at `Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\code-point-at` was empty for me, even after a clean install of Node. In your case, the directory should be `/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/code-point-at`.

I downloaded a copy of `code-point-at` from its Github repository at https://github.com/sindresorhus/code-point-at/tags, and manually copied the files into the directory. Once this was done, NPM appears to function normally for me.